# Changing editable content from true to false using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable, client-side

So I'm trying to override or nullify *contenteditable="true"* with js because Notion Enhancer as far as I know does not have the option to add html files. They do have the option of adding css and client side javascript, so I'm trying to turn the contenteditable false using js. I've tried many options, but nothing seems to be working. Does anyone have any ideas on how to turn it false through js without touching the HTML?

[This is the html markup.](http://jsfiddle.net/spencershastings/Lv4xa1ts/41/)

```
  <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Helvetica, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, Arial, sans-serif, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Symbol&quot;; font-weight: 600; font-size: 1.5em; line-height: 1.3; color: inherit; fill: inherit;">
    <div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Heading 2" data-root="true" class="notranslate" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; caret-color: rgb(55, 53, 47); padding: 3px 2px;">Monday</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I said, the HTML is non-negotiable, so everything would have to be through css or js. And I'd like to make the contenteditable false to change the padding around a heading.

Comment: Fiddle works fine for me, I cannot edit the `contenteditable` tag.

Comment: The fiddle you have linked to already works. The content cannot be edited. Please check again.

Comment: @NineBerry Sorry, maybe I'm just dumb, but I'm a little confused. There is no way to change contenteditable=true to false without touching the html? like, leaving contenteditable=true and making it false through js. otherwise I do not know how to override contenteditable. I'm trying to do this so I can add padding to the notranslate class.

Comment: @Yuan-HaoChiang I think my question wasn't clear. essentially, I want to override contenteditable with my own css to change the padding, because I would be unable to change the html in notion. I can add css/js files though, so that's why I'm trying to figure out how to do so with css or js. or both.

Comment: You already do change contentEditable to false via javascript in the Fiddle that you link to.

Comment: It's unclear what contentEditable has to do with padding. Maybe you can clarify this part.

Comment: @NineBerry essentially I want to change the padding of the class containing "Monday." but its contenteditable is set to true, and I don't know how to override it or change it to false through css or js (I cannot change the html on notion). so I've been trying to figure out how to change the padding around "Monday" (class is .notranslate), and I think the only way I found is through somehow turning contenteditable from true to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue here has nothing to do with the `contentEditable` attribute.

The issue is that the `div` tag in the html code contains a `style` attribute which already specifies values for `padding`. These values specified in the html code have a higher priority than specifications made in the css.

**Possible Solution 1:**

Use the `!important` marker in the css to have the definitions in the css overwrite the padding settings made in the code for that rule:

```
.notion-sub_header-block .notranslate {
  background-color: #fed2e4;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding:30px !important;
}
```

[Fiddle for Solution 1](http://jsfiddle.net/6esxam54/)

- See [Documentation on Specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to learn about `!important`

**Possible Solution 2:**

Use JavaScript to remove the `padding` from the `style` attribute from the html tag.

```
var editableElements = document.querySelectorAll("[class=notranslate");
    
for (var i = 0; i < editableElements.length; ++i) {
  editableElements[i].style.padding = "";
}
```

[Fiddle for Solution 2](http://jsfiddle.net/dk75cme9/2/)

Solution 1 is more elegant in this context because there's no need for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("table").contentEditable = "true";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference only this specific div maybe we should use the placeholder to locate it:

```
document.querySelector('div[placeholder="Heading 2"]').contentEditable=false;
```

Testing here, ate least in firefox, the contentEditable must have this case with capital E on Editable when setting it.

Comment: but would I be able to style the placeholder through css or js after? because it's still not working for me. I'm essentially trying to change the padding but I cannot because of the contenteditable. so if I rendered it false, I thought I could do my own styling with the placeholder.

Comment: yes you can. for example: `document.querySelector('div[placeholder="Heading 2"]').style.backgroundColor='yellow';` will work just as before changing the `contentEditable` flag